# How to open android adb from command prompt?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new bee in ANDROID , so for that I am unable to view, delete, insert data into database(SQLite), from command Prompt. I have installed my ANDROID in "F:\PROJECTS\ANDROID\android-sdk_r10-windows\android-sdk-windows". So any help will really be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the command prompt Go to this path or set as classpath F:\PROJECTS\ANDROID\android-sdk_r10-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools

Then type

```
adb shell
```

u will see:

```
#
```

Type

```
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/yourdbname
```

You will enter your database

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your db from promt. Your database is located at /data/data/your.package/databases/your_db so it's in your application's private directory e.g no other applications have access to it. So one solution is to have rooted phone. And the other is to copy the file from your's applications directory to the sdcard and then handle it as normal. So from your application you have to do something like this in your application

```
copyFile("/data/data/your.package/databases/your_db", "/sdcard/your_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

in desktop, right click on MyComputer>properties>advanced>Environment Variables>path edit it
append this F:\Projects\Android\android-sdk_r10-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
now, open command prompt & ur adb is ready to work from any path