# showing data from database in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to show large data from database.i have done googling,,on the based of it

I am attaching the two classes that i have used
http://pastebin.com/XfXMU3Kq

http://pastebin.com/xKAWd1wd

can anyone tell me how to show the full data from database.I dont know why data is not showing in database

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Comment: Which type of error you got ? And please check your code in your insertData Method you have given comment while inserting data into the data base at Row No. 76.

Comment: @idroid should i send u database ?

Comment: No need of send database. Just Put the Error log of u got. And if u want to check your database then try this from shell commend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800469/how-to-open-android-adb-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes about SQLLite database concepts.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/55.html

Comment: ,,,,,this data i have to show on a particular item of a list,,