# order by sum (score) desc returns wrong result

Tags: android, sql, sum, sql-order-by

Don't know what is causing this but I try to get the level which  has the heighest score-sum of all answers of that level.

```
Cursor c = myDataBase
                .rawQuery(
                        "select level "
                                + "from answers where player ='"
                                + player
                                + "' group by level order by sum (score) desc",
                        null);
```

All answers of a certain level have a score value. It constantly returns level 10 (of 10 levels) while actually another level has the highest score... if I apply an asc order, it works just fine :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get only level with highest score then try using `having` as below:

```
            "select level "
            + "from answers where player ='"
            + player
            + "' group by level "
            + " having sum (score) = max(sum (score))";
```

EDIT:

```
            "select level from (select level, max(levelscore) as maxscore from "+
                               +" (select level, sum (score) as levelscore, "
                               + " from answers where player ='"
                               + player
                               + "' group by level )"
            + " ) where levelscore = maxscore";
```

or

```
           "select level from "+
                   +" (select level, sum (score) as levelscore, "
                   + " from answers where player ='"
                   + player
                   + "' group by level )"
                   + "order by levelscore desc LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: It gives an error... 12-03 16:27:55.602: E/AndroidRuntime(29505): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function sum(): , while compiling: select level from answers where player ='yesr' group by level having sum (score) = max(sum (score))
Also, can you point out why this should work (aside from the error) and mine doesn't?

Comment: @MatthiasVanb The basic difference between your query and this one is: this return the level with max score while your query returns all sorted. I updated the query as in the answer with putting `sum` in select. Can you please try?

Comment: I tried it, and gave an error that I had to use a group by clause before 'having', so I changed it to: "select level from (select level, sum (score) as levelscore"
                                + " from answers where player ='"
                                + player
                                + "' group by level )"
             + " group by level having max(levelscore) = levelscore" But this returns just the first level, not the one with the heighest score..

Comment: @MatthiasVanb: Strange. I updated the query in the answer by putting max also in the select. Hope this works.

Comment: Mmm, damn, Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function sum(): , while compiling: select level from (select level, sum (score) as levelscore,  max(sum (score)) as maxscore from answers where player ='yesr' group by level )  where levelscore = maxscore

Comment: @MatthiasVanb Looks like its not taking max and sum together. I updated the answer with two possible variations. Hope both should work. Can you please try?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT level, SUM( score ) AS scoresum
FROM answers
WHERE player = ?
GROUP BY level
ORDERBY scoresum DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

and why not this statement (easier)

```
SELECT TOP 1 level 
FROM answers 
WHERE player = {player} 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

be careful, If you execute this query BEFORE you "saved" the first result of the player, you will get no result...

Serge

Comment: Well I do combine the query with some more vars I get out, I shortened it because that is the part of the query which goes wrong. Do you have any idea why the asc is doing fine and the desc doesn't ?

Comment: Well I only know that SQLlite do a lot of magic behind the scenes. Can you check the declaration of the "score" field, verify that it contains only numeric values?

When things go wrong, I usually do a manual query via adb/SQLlite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800469/how-to-open-android-adb-from-command-prompt

Comment: It does only contain numeric items... and is never empty